# Keras softmax layer output not summing 1

Tags: keras, text-classification, multiclass-classification, softmax

I'm working on a four class multi-class text classification problem. I used a pretrained masked language model and add a classification head. The model takes two text sources as input and should output the normalized probabilities.

Here is my model

```
# Text input 1
    def build_model():
      inputs_descr = keras.Input(shape=(seq_length_descr,), dtype=tf.int32, name = 'input_1')
      out_descr = pretrained_lm.layers[1](inputs_descr)
      out_descr = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, activation = 'tanh', dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0))(out_descr)
      out_descr = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(out_descr)
    
    # Text Input 2
      inputs_tw = keras.Input(shape=(seq_length_tw,), dtype=tf.int32, name = 'input_2')
      out_tw = pretrained_lm.layers[1](inputs_tw)
      out_tw = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, activation = 'tanh', dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0))(out_tw)
      out_tw = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(out_tw)
    
      last_hidden_state_conc = concatenate([out_descr, out_tw]) 
    
      out = layers.Dense(60, activation="relu")(last_hidden_state_conc)
      out = layers.Dropout(0.2)(out)
      out = layers.Dense(30, activation="relu")(out)
      out = layers.Dropout(0.2)(out)
    
    # Classification node
      output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, 
                                   activation = 'softmax',
                                   )(out)
    
      lm_mediano_multi = tf.keras.Model([inputs_descr, inputs_tw], output)
      return lm_mediano_multi
```

The problem is the output probabilities for each sample do not add up to 1, which it should given the softmax activation in the last layer.

```
array([[1.0000e+00, 5.9605e-08, 2.0027e-05, 7.7486e-07],
       [1.0000e+00, 7.1526e-07, 7.0095e-05, 1.6034e-05],
       [1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 8.3447e-07, 1.1921e-07],
       [1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 2.5034e-06, 5.9605e-08],
       [7.3975e-01, 2.6836e-03, 2.1460e-01, 4.3060e-02],
       [1.0000e+00, 4.7684e-07, 6.8307e-05, 6.3181e-06],
       [1.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 3.8147e-06, 7.1526e-07]])
```

Just in case, I also use `keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16")`.

I haven´t found an explanation for this.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are letting people guess why you think these values do not sum to 1.0, you should explain us.

Comment: I don´t think I follow. The output probabilities for each sample should add up to 1 but they do not, which is pretty clear for samples 1-4 and 6, 7.

Comment: Its not pretty clear to me, instead of having to guess, gives your interpretation, to what value do they sum? Make the sum using numpy (not from the printed values as they are rounded) Also this could just be floating point imprecision. You need to be precise and not leave details loose.